# dart final property can change values

Tags: flutter, dart

Hey guys I've searched the answers and didn't find it, so I'm asking.

I have a class with a list property, Dart Lint said to put the keyword 'final' before it.
The final keyword should prevent the values to change, or I got it wrong?

```
class Questions {
final List<Question> _questionList = [
Question('Is the ocean blue', true),
Question('Is the sky blue', true),
];

//method that shouldn't work
void setQuestionAnswer(int questionNumber, bool newAns) {
    _questionBank[questionNumber].questionAnswer = newAns;
  }
}

//another file that have the class to the list above
class Question {
  String questionText;
  bool questionAnswer;

  Question(this.questionText, this.questionAnswer);
}

Questions questionsk = Questions();

//this actually works, but a final property shouldn't be able to change
// values, why it works? I can change the value
questionsk.setQuestionAnswer(questionNumber, false);
```

Comment: `final` prevents a variable from being *reassigned*.  It does not prevent the *object* from being mutated.

Answer (score 2):

The `final` keyword means you cannot assign a new value to `__questionList`.

For example, this code would give a compiler error:

```
_questionList = <Question>[];
```

You *can* however, do anything you want with the initial instance of the object. In case of a list you can change entries, add entries, remove entries or anything else.

Comment: I thought "not to be able to reassigned" and "immutable" were synonyms. I actually didn't quite understand yet, what reassigned means.
In your example seems that we are just clearing the list, which would be equivalent of removing entries too. I don't know. I have to read about it, if I find some good article.

Comment: I think I got this, I can only use the 'equal' sign just once, but I can add and remove entries as you said, thanks for answering.

Comment: Just made a test, if I put a final on questionAnswer of the class Question, which is used by class Questions, than it generates an error, so I undestood, so the External Object with the final List has a list that can't be reassigned, but the object from inside can, that's why I can change the answers.